# How to respond with HTML or JSON depending on the request in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

Let's say I have a model called `User` with its basic REST CRUD (GET, POST, DELETE, UPDATE).

When I go to `user/4` (where 4 is an ID of a User that *doesn't* exist), there are two cases:

1. If I'm doing it with a REST client like Postman, I'd get a 404 and nothing else.
2. If I'm on the browser, I'll get a 404 page (with text, images, etc), which is defined in the views folder.

**How can I achieve this for `findOne`, `find`, and other URLs?** I want to be able to have JSON-only responses, and HTML pages responses for different types of requests. But I don't want to override the functions, because the ORM is already doing a lot of work that I don't want to lose.

**EDIT:** My solution would be to leave the API with a prefix, such as `/api/user/4` and the HTML response without the prefix `user/4`, but I'd like to see more elegant solutions.

**EDIT 2:** I just decided to go all JSON, and use a REST service only with an independent front end ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the headers sent by the API client, I see two clean semantic solutions, based on the headers sent :

- you could rely on the `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` header to recognize Ajax queries
- rely on a `Accept: text/json` header to explicitly request json

You could also modify the url with file extensions to request a specific response, `user/4.html` => send html, `user/4` => send json.